# How to insert data correctly from a form into a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to put my given data from the form in to my table but the data is always under ID :/

In my form I can input a name, birthday and a place and this should be stored in the table. And the ID should start with 1.
I'm not sure how to implement it.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already referencing `jQuery` and partially using it, so using jQuery for the rest too you can make a row template and map the values to it before appending it to the table, similar to the below.

You can add a lot more abstraction and turn each set of values into an artist object you pass around but to keep close to your sample I only did mimimum changes.

I did add favorites though as well but not sure how you want to display that.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var allArtists = [];

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var $rowTemplate = $('<tr><td data-id="id"></td><td data-id="name"></td><td data-id="geburtsort"></td><td data-id="geburtsdatum"></td><td data-id="favorite"></td></tr>');

    var artistName = $("#name").val();
    var ort = $("#ort").val();
    var datum = $("#datum").val();
    var favourite = $("[name=Favorit]").is(':checked');

    allArtists.push([artistName, ort, datum]);

    var rowId = allArtists.length;
    
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=id]').text(rowId);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=name]').text(artistName);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsort]').text(ort);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=geburtsdatum]').text(datum);
    $rowTemplate.find('[data-id=favorite]').text(favourite);

    $("#table tbody").append($rowTemplate);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="send">
  <label>Name des Künstlers</label>
  <br>
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name des Künstlers" />
  <br>

  <label>Ort</label>
  <br>
  <input id="ort" type="text" placeholder="Woher stammt der Künstler" />
  <br>

  <label>Geburtsdatum</label>
  <br>
  <input id="datum" type="text" placeholder="Wann ist der Künstler geboren?" />
  <br>
</form>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Favorit" value="Favorit"> Favorit
  <p>

    <input type="button" id="submit" name="senden" value="Senden">
    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Geburtsort</th>
          <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
          <th>Favorit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a cell for every seperate "thing", just as in HTML. Every cell needs his own textnode.

```
window.onload = function(){
var allArtists = [];


$('#submit').click(function(){
var artistName = $("#name").val();
var ort = $("#ort").val();
var datum = $("#datum").val();
allArtists.push([artistName,ort,datum])

var tableRef = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
var newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
var newCell3  = newRow.insertCell(2);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText1  = document.createTextNode(allArtists['artistName']);
var newText2  = document.createTextNode(allArtists['ort']);
var newText3  = document.createTextNode(allArtists['datum']);
newCell1.appendChild(newText1);
  newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
  newCell3.appendChild(newText3);
  });
};
```

Comment: document.createTextNode(allArtists['artistName']); this part doesn't work. I get undefined :/

Comment: Check the allArtists array in your console, is it defined over there?

Answer (score 1):

First put your headers in into thead so we only get real data inside tbody. Modify your html like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Geburtsort</th>
        <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
        <th>Favorit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Inside your click event you can fetch the input the way you do, generate the id from your array length and push it into the html(DOM) with jquery which you already use.

```
var artistName = $("#name").val();
var ort = $("#ort").val();
var datum = $("#datum").val();
var id = allArtists.length; 
allArtists.push({ id: id, name: artistName, ort: ort, datum: datum });

$('#table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td>'+artistName+'</td><td>'+ort+'</td><td>'+datum+'</td><td>-</td></tr>');
```

$('#table tbody') will look for an element with the id of table (#-prefix indicates an id) and then a body element below (no-prefix indicates an tag name).

.append  does append the string as html inside the found element

This should do as a starter ^^
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use jQuery, here is a much more convenient method to do it:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var artistName = $("#name").val();
  var ort = $("#ort").val();
  var datum = $("#datum").val();
  var rowsCount = $("#table tbody tr").length;

  var row = "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + (rowsCount + 1) + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + artistName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ort + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + datum + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + true + "</td>" +
    "</tr>";

  $("#table tbody").append(row);
});
```

The above work creates a row for the table and appends it to `tbody` of your table.